# Why is yum picking a lower version to install

Tags: centos, yum

For reasons that I cannot control, I am being forced to roll my own rpms for PHP under CentOS 7.4. I have built rpms for php 7.2.5 and installed them in a local repository. `yum install php` picks up the local version and the package is installed under /usr/local. My problem is with php-pear. For some reason, yum wants to pick up the stock version of php-pear instead of my version, even though my version has the higher version number.

```
# yum --showduplicates list php-pear
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
php-pear.noarch    1.10.5-1.el7.centos    nci-f
php-pear.noarch    1:1.9.4-21.el7         base
php-pear.noarch    1:1.9.4-21.el7         base
php-pear.noarch    1:1.9.4-21.el7         base
# yum install php-pear
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-bz2 for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tokenizer for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xml for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-zlib for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-ftp for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-pcre for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
 ...
```

I have set the priority of the nci-f repository to 1 with no effect. I know that I can use `yum install php-pear-7.2.5-1.el7.centos` to install the specific package but both want to use the simpler command (on 400+ servers) and want to make sure updates work in the future.

Also, in my .spec file for the php-pear package I do have the line

```
Obsoletes: php-pear  <= 1:1.9.4
```

Why is yum picking the lower version package and how can I get it to prefer my package instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the epoch (the `1` in `1:1.9.4-21`), it overrides your (default) epoch `0` packages.

The epoch was introduced in rpm packages precisely to be able to "fix" version numbers that go backwards. Use with *extreme* caution.

Besides, the RHEL/Centos packages probably include lots of local fixes/tweaks. I'd suggest you start with the official source packages and tweak those, replacing the sources with newer versions as needed.

Comment: The official source packages are for php 5.4 - that's a lot of tweaking to bring them up to php 7.2.